# goswagger generate swagger.yaml

Tags: go, swagger

I'm trying to generate swagger.yaml for go. Here is the link to the goswagger documentation https://goswagger.io/install.html

I tried the following:

```
docker pull quay.io/goswagger/swagger

alias swagger='docker run --rm -it  --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -e GOPATH=$(go env GOPATH):/go -v $HOME:$HOME -w $(pwd) quay.io/goswagger/swagger'
swagger version
```

> version: v0.29.0 commit: 53696caa1e8a4e5b483c87895d54eda202beb3b0

I've tried `export GOCACHE=$HOME/Library/Caches/go-build`, `export GOCACHE=off`, `export GOCACHE=/tmp/`,
`export GOCACHE=$HOME/.cache/go-build`

but when I run

```
swagger generate spec -o ./swagger.yaml
```

I always get the following error

> err: exit status 1: stderr: failed to initialize build cache at
> /.cache/go-build: mkdir /.cache: permission denied

If I'm reading the error right it seems to be trying to write to the root directory instead of my home directory. Here are my `go env` vars

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/micahkimel/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/micahkimel/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/micahkimel/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/micahkimel/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.18.3"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/Users/micahkimel/go/src/GoDir/go.mod"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/4d/4xnmhr0j0478jh_6btr0nds80000gn/T/go-build1145095409=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the github issues here https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/issues/2633

I just needed to set the `GOCACHE` in the docker alias

```
alias swagger='docker run --rm -it  --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -e GOCACHE=/tmp -e  GOPATH=$(go env GOPATH):/go -v $HOME:$HOME -w $(pwd) quay.io/goswagger/swagger'
```